# Reading XML working in my computer but not in my Android phone

Tags: c#, android, xml, unity-game-engine

Following code works perfect in my computer but when I try to run it in my Android Phone, it does not work.

```
string path = @"Assets\Layout\XML\file" + select.ToString() + @".xml";
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
List<Name> listnames = (List<Name>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

How can I make the code work in my Android Phone?

Comment: You need to specify what programming language you are using on the android device

Comment: I wrote c# and unity, but somebody removed it. @KenTucker

Comment: *it does not work* -- what happens specifically?  If there is an exception, what is it?  `FileNotFoundException`?  `InvalidOperationException`?  If an exception, what is the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the message, traceback and inner exception (if any)?

Comment: "It does not work" means it does not read XML elements in android phone. I think there is an another way to read the elements in Android phone.

Here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/132753/how-do-i-read-xml-on-iphone.html

It is explained very well but I could not convert a List<String> to xml document. @dbc

Comment: No need to use a stringbuilder.  Use LoadXml instead of Load.  Try this : XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); xmlDoc.LoadXml("xml string");

Comment: @jdweng I am not familiar with that. If you have a free time, can you explain it with the same name I used in my first code? If you want, you check the rest of my code from following link: http://codeshare.io/L30eJ

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question.  An XML is normally a single string.  So using LoadXml() method is used.  For some reason you have an array (List<string>) along with XmlTextReader.  If you are just reading data from the cloud then a single string should be returned.  Now don't get the input results confused with the output results.  It looks like you output is going to be an array of strings.  It would be helpful to see a sample of the xml.  An XML should have only a single root tag.  You can only have arrays in xml l if they are child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost gave up but finally solved it. Unity converts everything to binary variable so that the first thing you need to do is to convert all xml files you have to txt and copy them to "Assets/Resources" folder.

Then, you can use following code:

```
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("file" + select.ToString()) as TextAsset;
    Stream s = new MemoryStream(asset.bytes);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
    List<Name> listnames = (List<Name>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```